# Blogger Post disappear or duplicate

Tags: html, xml, blogger, configure

Create a blog of videos, but simply the posts have disappeared or duplicated I tried to increase or decrease the posts by page but no advance. Example of my blog In this blog I created 100 post, 21 per page, notice that the post 79,78,57,56,15,14.13.12 disappeared and the 36,35 double When I try to increase or decrease the posts per page makes the situation worse. Can someone help me configure

xml do blogger https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEzYNgWrBWVWU1xYl9DYkdCb1k/view

Comment: No one is going to be able to see that file that you have linked, you would need to make it publicly available

Comment: Could you share the URL of the blog where you are facing this issue?